# TYPO3 9.5.x creates a link to xml sitemap

Tags: typo3, seo, typo3-9.x, sitemap.xml

I'm using this code to create a xml sitemap on a multidomain website (.de and .com):

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
                pages {
                    config {
                        excludedDoktypes = 137, 138
                        additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is a XML-file to the real sitemap. Is this valid?

.../sitemap.xml:

[image]

The real sitemap when I click the link (.../sitemap.xml?sitemap=pages&cHash=d65c2c32882eb9d88ac8d6050159a9c7)

[image: 3]

Comment: Yes, that's allowed: https://www.sitemaps.org/de/protocol.html#index

Comment: Thanks/Danke! ;)

Comment: @julian-hofmann, you should make an answer from your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's allowed: https://www.sitemaps.org/de/protocol.html#index

In short: for larger websites, you should split your sitemap into multiple files. It's also a possibility if you have different kinds of content and the sitemaps need to be generated separately (e.g. news records and pages)